# Show background on text on Edittext separated by , or space tapping on it removes it from edittext view

Tags: android, background, android-edittext

I want something like this in Edittext . When I select some contact it shows up in Edittext with that light background and automatically separated .

[image: Oneplus Messaging app]

This is what I made . I am trying to achieve something like above .

[image: My App]

Comment: https://github.com/robertlevonyan/materialChipView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has generally been referred to as a "chips" UI. It is not built into the Android SDK, but there are third-party [libraries](https://android-arsenal.com/search?q=chips) that support it, such as:

[ChipsLibrary](https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/ChipsLibrary)

[MaterialChipView](https://github.com/robertlevonyan/materialChipView)

[MaterialChipsInput](https://github.com/pchmn/MaterialChipsInput)

Comment: Exactly what I wanted ! Thank you